# Is it possible to store a regex match and use part of it as a list enumerator?

Tags: c#, regex

I have created a MadLibs style game where the user enters responses to prompts which in turn replace blanks, represented by %s0, %s1 etc., in a story. I have this working using a for loop but someone else suggested I could do it using regex. What I have so far is below, which replaces all instances of %s+number with "wibble". What I was wondering is if it is possible to store the number found by the regex in a temporary variable and in turn use that to return a value from the list Words? E.g. `return Regex.Replace(story, pattern, Global.Words[x]);` where `x` is the number returned by the regex pattern as it goes over the string.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Globals.Words = new List<string>();
        Globals.Words.Add("nathan");
        Globals.Words.Add("bob");

        var text = "Once upon a time there was a %s0 and it was %s1";
        Console.WriteLine(FindEscapeCharacters(text));
    }

    public static string FindEscapeCharacters(string story)
    {
        var pattern = @"%s([0-9]+)";
        return Regex.Replace(story, "%s([0-9]+)", "wibble");
    }
```

Thanks in advance, Nathan.

Comment: Can you give an example with input and output expected pls? A lot of words and I can't understand clearly

Comment: The input would be `var text` as above. The output would look something like `Once upon a time there was a nathan and it was bob`. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are very close in your attempt with `Regex.Replace`; the last step is to change *constant* `"wibble"` into *lambda* `match => how_to_replace_the_match`:

```
  var text = "Once upon a time there was a %s0 and it was %s1";

  // Once upon a time there was a nathan and it was bob
  var result = Regex.Replace(
    text, 
   "%s([0-9]+)", 
    match => Globals.Words[int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value)]);
```

**Edit:** In case you don't want working with capturing groups by their *numbers*, you can name them *explicitly*:

```
  // Once upon a time there was a nathan and it was bob
  var result = Regex.Replace(
    text, 
   "%s(?<number>[0-9]+)", 
    match => Globals.Words[int.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value)]);
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind. I'm unsure what `match.Groups[1].Value` does? Where does the 1 come from?

Comment: `match.Groups[1].Value` is the value of the 1st capturing group `0th` is the enire match, `1st` corresponds to parenthesis `([0-9]+)`. You can put it *explictly*: `"%s(?<number>[0-9]+)"` and then `Globals.Words[int.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value)]);`

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer to your question about regexes, but if I understand you correctly, there is an easier way to do this:

```
string baseString = "I have a {0} {1} in my {0} {2}.";

List<string> words = new List<string>() { "red", "cat", "hat" };

string outputString = String.Format(baseString, words.ToArray());
```

`outputString` will be `I have a red cat in my red hat.`.

Is that not what you want, or is there more to your question that I'm missing?

---

**Minor elaboration**

`String.Format` uses the following signature:

```
string Format(string format, params object[] values)
```

The neat thing about `params` is that you can either list values separately:

```
var a = String.Format("...", valueA, valueB, valueC);
```

but you can also pass in an array directly:

```
var a = String.Format("...", valueArray);
```

Note that you can't mix and match the two approaches.

Comment: Yeah, that's much simpler.

Comment: Yes that's the output I was looking for. I did something similar by using a for loop and string.replace. The question was to try and help me determine if I could do the same thing using regex as was suggested to me. I'm not very familiar with regex so I thought it might be a good exercise in trying to get to grips with it.

Comment: @nathanjw: Regexes are a powerful tool, and any practice with them is useful. But I've also learned that regexes should really be avoided when easier options exist, they can become hard to maintain or alter. You're of course free to solve it however you want, just keep in mind that using regexes as the go-to solution is usually overkill and you're better off avoiding them when reasonable alternatives exist.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on regex, I'll keep it in mind. I try and avoid where possible :) As you say, the `String.Format()` approach is a lot simpler and cleaner for my purpose here.

Comment: After testing this out I think I'll replace my for loop with this as it is more flexible and allows me to format the input string better. Thanks :-D

Answer (score 0):

There is [an overload of `Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) that, rather than taking a string for the last argument, takes a `MatchEvaluator` delegate - a function that takes a `Match` object and returns a `string`.

You could make that function parse the integer from the `Match`'s `Groups[1].Value` property and then use that to index into your list, returning the `string` you find.